# Topological semi-direct products

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-groups, locally-compact-groups

In [Kaniuth, Taylor, Induced representations of locally compact groups](https://www.zbmath.org/?q=an%3A1263.22005) on pages 9-10 it's claimed that if $G$ is a locally compact group with closed subgroups $N,H$, with $N$ normal in $G$, with $N\cap H=\{e\}$, and with $NH=G$, then $G$ is a topological semidirect product of $N$ and $H$.

We copy the [algebraic proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product), defining an action $\alpha_h(n) = hnh^{-1}$ which will be suitably continuous, allowing us to construct $N \rtimes_\alpha H$.  The map $N \rtimes_\alpha H \rightarrow G; (n,h) \mapsto nh$ is an isomorphism of groups, and clearly continuous.

> Why is the inverse of this map continuous?

You would need to show that given nets $(n_i)\subseteq N, (h_i)\subseteq H$ with $n_ih_i\rightarrow e$, then necessarily $n_i\rightarrow e, h_i\rightarrow e$.  I don't see how to do this.

(Under some conditions, e.g. that $N \rtimes_\alpha H$ is $\sigma$-compact, there are open mapping theorems for locally compact groups available, which would show this.  For example, see Corollary 1.7 in [Hofmann, Morris, Open Mapping Theorem for Topological Groups (pdf)](https://sidneymorris.net/Morris141.pdf).)

Comment: There is counter-example on MathOverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/a/425559

Answer (score 0):

**Added:** Below is my previous attempt at an answer.

It seems for $G$ be to the internal topological semidirect product of $N$ and $H$ with $H$ acting on $N$ via conjugation by definition $G$ ought to have the product topology $N\times H$. The continuity of $\pi: G\to H$ I (mistakenly) use below is in fact equivalent to this (see e.g. Bourbaki's *General Topology*, Chapters 1-4, p.242.).

In general, if $G$ is a topological group, $N,H\leq G$ are subgroups with N normal such that $NH=G$ and $N\cap H=1$ (so that $G\cong N\rtimes^{\text{Alg}} H$ as groups without specified topologies), then one can form the external topological semidirect product $N\rtimes^{\text{Top}} H$. Then the map $N\rtimes^{\text{Top}} H\to G, (n,h)\mapsto nh$ is always an isomorphism of groups and is continuous, but its inverse need not be continuous (see again Bourbaki).

For an example of an algebraic internal semidirect product that is not a topological internal semidirect product see Roelke & Dierolf's *Uniform Structures on Topological Groups and Their Quotients*, p.121, Ex.6.18.a.

It remains to be seen if one assumes additionally that $G$ is locally compact and $N,H$ are closed one obtains that $G$ has the product topology automatically (which is what was asked originally). As of the writing this latest edit I have not been able to produce a counterexample or give a proof. (In the Roelke-Dierolf counterexample $N$ is dense and index $2$ it seems.)

I will add further details if I make any progress.

---

For any $g\in G$, there are unique $n_g\in N$ and $h_g\in H$ such that $g=n_g h_g$. $\pi:G\to H, g\mapsto h_g$ is a surjective topological group homomorphism with kernel $\ker(\pi)=N$. If $n_\bullet h_\bullet \to e$, then $h_\bullet=\pi(n_\bullet h_\bullet)\to \pi(e)=e$, hence also $h_\bullet^{-1}\to e$. Thus $n_\bullet=n_\bullet h_\bullet h_\bullet^{-1}\to e$.

Comment: This seems to use that $\pi$ is continuous.  But why is that so?

Comment: @MatthewDaws Indeed, I've added further details.

Comment: Thanks.  I am afraid I have a new question.  As $(NV) \cap (NH) = NV$, this seems to claim the following.  Given $v\in V$ and $n\in V$, $nv = n n_v h_v$ is the unique decomposition.  If $NV = N(V\cap H)$ then we can find $p\in N, k\in V\cap H$ with $pk = n n_v h_v$ so by uniqueness, $p=n n_v$ and $h_v = k$ so in particular $h_v \in V$.  However, $V$ could be any open set in $G$.  So why is it true that $V\subseteq G$ open implies that for $v\in V$ we have $h_v \in V$?

Comment: @MatthewDaws Doesn't what you wrote prove what you are asking? ($h_v$ may be identity)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.  I believe that my argument shows that $N(V\cap H) = NV$ only when, for _any_ open $V\subseteq G$ and _any_ $v\in V$ we have $h_v\in V$.  Why is this so?

Comment: @MatthewDaws You are right. For $G$ to be the internal topological semidirect product it seems one also needs the assumption that $G$ is homeomorphic to $N\times H$ (or equivalently $\pi$ to be continuous). I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Well, thank you anyway for your interest in this question!